# Failed to restart after installed APOC Plugin in Neo4j

Tags: plugins, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I would like to install the APOC plugin for Neo4j. However once generated jar file and restart, neo4j not able to restart again

Follow Guide
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/tree/3.1

Error msg:

```
ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component '          org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3b6579d6' was successfully initialized,           but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component '          org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3b6579d6' was successfully initialized,           but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.          database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3b6579d6' was successfully initialized, but failed to sta          rt. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(Serv          erStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:227)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.databa          se.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3b6579d6' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Pl          ease see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:4          43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:199)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDat          abaseFacadeFactory, /root/NEO4J_HOME/data/databases/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabase          FacadeFactory.java:193)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseF          acadeFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDataba          se.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:4          33)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.p          roc.Procedures@2200fd80' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attac          hed cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:4          43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabase          FacadeFactory.java:189)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ProcedureException: Unable to register procedure,           because the name `apoc.algo.betweenness` is already in use.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureRegistry.register(ProcedureRegistry.java:81)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:76)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:209)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:4          33)
        ... 11 more
```

the jar file name: apoc-3.1.0.4-SNAPSHOT-al.jar

neo4j version: 3.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stacktrace says: "the name `apoc.algo.betweenness` is already in use". So, perhaps you forgot to remove a previous APOC jar file from the `plugins` directory.